# Creating a dictionary from a separate list of keys and values using dict comprehension in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

A friend of mine and me were facing a tricky task today I thought would be worth sharing here.

This is the basis:

```
keys = ["name", "surname", "age"]
values = ['John    Miller    20',
          'James   Smith     30',
          'Gary    Jones     50'
         ]
d = {}
```

We would like to create a dictionary in the following format:

```
{'name': ['John', 'James', 'Gary'],
 'surname': ['Miller', 'Smith', 'Jones'],
 'age': [20, 30, 50]}
```

The tricky part is that we would like to do it in only one line.

I'm very interested in the approaches you'll come up with!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Try [CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> The tricky part is we would like to do it in only one line.

You could tie a few `zip`s together.

```
d = dict(zip(keys, list(zip(*[value.split() for value in values]))))
```

If you now do `print(d)` it would output:

```
{'name': ('John', 'James', 'Gary'), 'surname': ('Miller', 'Smith', 'Jones'), 'age': ('20', '30', '50')}
```

*This is of course assuming that `value.split()` always results in 3 values.*

**Edit:** If you want the tuples to be lists, then throw `list(a) for a in ...` into the mix:

```
d = dict(zip(keys, list(list(a) for a in zip(*[value.split() for value in values]))))
```

Which outputs:

```
{'name': ['John', 'James', 'Gary'], 'surname': ['Miller', 'Smith', 'Jones'], 'age': ['20', '30', '50']}
```

Comment: Could you output them as `lists` as well, using your line ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `numpy`?

```
import numpy as np

d = dict(zip(keys, np.array([i.split() for i in values]).transpose().tolist()))

{'age': ['20', '30', '50'],
 'name': ['John', 'James', 'Gary'],
 'surname': ['Miller', 'Smith', 'Jones']}
```

Benchmarks: Looks like @Vallentin's answer is faster

```
time d = dict(zip(keys, list(zip(*[value.split() for value in values]))))

CPU times: user 23 µs, sys: 1 µs, total: 24 µs
Wall time: 29.1 µs

time d = dict(zip(keys, np.array([i.split() for i in values]).transpose().tolist()))

CPU times: user 41 µs, sys: 6 µs, total: 47 µs
Wall time: 47.9 µs
```